# Why am I getting a Token Comma Expected error when trying to pull in this file?

Tags: powerquery

I get a "Token comma expected" Error. It's highlighting the "in".

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\arrow\Dropbox (Arrow Academy)\BILLING\MEDICAID\1TM - EE MA Numbers for Billing TEST.xlsx"){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"MA#-INITIALS", type text}, {"FIRST NAME", type text}, {"LAST NAME, FIRST NAME", type text}, {"MA SPECIALTY", type text}, {"POSITION", type text}, {"INITIALS", type text}, {"INITIALS2", type text}}) 
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: why  not just let PQ generate the code?  data ... get data .. from file ... from workbook, highlight the relevant tab, and hit edit button

Answer (score 0):

```
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\arrow\Dropbox (Arrow Academy)\BILLING\MEDICAID\1TM - EE MA Numbers for Billing TEST.xlsx")){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
```

`Excel.CurrentWorkbook()` was not closed.